how can I change the radius of a circle without changing its thickness?
I have to make a project where the thickness of the circle is 0.001 m, and the diameter of the circle should increase and the thickness remain unchanged. How to do it?

That is, the thickness is 0.001m, the diameter is 0.05m

the thickness is 0.001m, the diameter is 0.09m

the thickness is 0.001m, the diameter is 0.13m



How to do this without changing the thickness of the circle each time

look, I should have rings with an internal diameter of 0.05m and an external diameter of 0.051m.  the next circle has a diameter of 0.09m on the inside and 0.091m on the outside.  that is, this gray space should be equal to 1 millimeter. and how can I make it so that when the internal temperature of this ring increases, the gray space does not increase, but remains equal to 1 millimeter

You could do it in several steps with the Mesh: Edit Mesh Tools and the Ctrl E > Offset Edges > Offset for each circle, then bridge them?

I'm sorry but I guess this needs a little more clarification on how you want to change it: do you simply want to create several rings in different sizes and they stay like that or do you need the size change to be animated with keyframes? Or you want to change sizes manually by scaling? Or what exactly is your goal here? Because different goals might require different solutions.

@GordonBrinkmann: that's the first question i totally understand and you don't :D this sentence makes it clear (i think): make a project where the thickness of the circle is 0.001 m, and the diameter of the circle should increase and the thickness remain unchanged.  -> just animating the radius/diameter with constant thickness

@Chris Oh, I read it like this too ;) But it would not be the first time here that something is not meant as it sounds - and still it does not explain if one should still be able to freely change the size of the circle by scaling or if it will be animated with keyframes. Or if it has to be a mesh or if a Bézier circle would be suitable, too. Or - if manual scaling is desired - if scaling can be done in Edit Mode or needs to be done in Object Mode etc.

@GordonBrinkmann: since he wrote concrete values, i think shape key is fine. If not, he has to go with animation nodes/geometry nodes/sverchok anyway. But for sure not by modeling ;)

@Chris I think so, too... that's why your answer got a +1. But it's happening so often (this week already) that people ask how to do something (with concrete examples) and the answer is quite simple, but then they say, "well that was just a simple illustration to show the issue, actually it is much more complex stuff." So when I think there is room for interpretation, I ask. And yes, for other methods other tools are needed - that's why I said depending on what the goal is, the solution might depend as well.

@GordonBrinkmann: everybody who answers here regularly has made this experience...in former times, i then changed my answer. Meanwhile i answer that they didn't ask that and that they pls ask a new question - so they learn how to ask as well ;)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

First add a circle, enter your radius: 0.05

Go into Edit Mode, add another circle, radius: 0.051
A Select All then under Edge > Bridge Edge Loops.
Go into Object Mode, create two shape keys, select the inner circle
(you have to enable looptools add-on):
enter your radius: 0.13
Click circle:

select the outer radius, do the same with radius 0.131 
Now you can animate it with the value in shape keys:

